# Installer for windows that copy files and creates shortcut

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I have few documentation ASP, html, js files in a folder. They are developed to be on server but they are also supplied with product for offline use. So user can directly use them by opening in web browser.

Since this are developed for very non technical factory workers, I created a installer which copies files to c:/program files/my application and then creates shortcut on desktop to one of the html file. I have used install shield in VS 2015 to create installer for my small c# projects, I tried with this one, but VS froze (stopped responding). I think because all files combined are 216 MB. It took tine and I got single installation file. I wanted to set it up by folder instead, since if documentation is updated I can make changes to file I don't want to build installation again.

suppose my folder documentation contains some files,

I just need equivalent of

```
cp  documentation 'c:/programs and files/my documentation'
```

and then create shortcut to default html file on desktop.

Comment: Can you try using WIX tool?

Comment: Your question is confusing. ASP/HTML/JS suggests you have developed a Web application, but you would not install a Web application to C:\Program Files and create a desktop shortcut for it. There seems to be some information missing.

Comment: Product documentation is created in html format and few in pdf format. These files are provided to the customer to open directly (company application).